# Inconsistently slow queries in production (RDS)

Tags: python, postgresql, amazon-rds, gevent

First, the server setup:

- nginx frontend to the world
- gunicorn running a Flask app with gevent workers
- Postgres database, connection pooled in the app, running from Amazon RDS, connected with psycopg2 patched to work with gevent

The problem I'm encountering is inexplicably slow queries that are sometimes running on the order of 100ms or so (ideal), but which often spike to 10s or more.  While time is a parameter in the query, the difference between the fast and slow query happens much more frequently than a change in the result set. This doesn't seem to be tied to any meaningful spike in CPU usage, memory usage, read/write I/O, request frequency, etc.  It seems to be arbitrary.

I've tried:

- **Optimizing the query** - definitely valid, but it runs quite well locally, as well as any time I've tried it directly on the server through psql.
- **Running on a larger/better RDS instance** - I'm currently working on an m3.medium instance with PIOPS and not coming close to that read rate, so I don't think that's the issue.
- **Tweaking the number of gunicorn workers** - I thought this could be an issue, if the psycopg2 driver is having to context switch excessively, but this had no effect.
- **More** - I've been working for a decent amount of time at this, so these were just a couple of the things I've tried.

Does anyone have ideas about how to debug this problem?

Comment: Sounds like it could be bursty checkpoint activity; enable `log_checkpoints` and set a suitable `log_min_duration_statement` to see the queries of interest, and/or use `auto_explain`.

Comment: Could this be possible if there are no writes taking place at the time? The database is primarily read-only (with a notable exception, but that's not running at the moment).  My understanding is that checkpoints are for writes, not reads.

Comment: Checkpoints are still done when there's no user-level write activity, but they're generally not noticeable then. So no, I wouldn't say that's it.

Answer (score 1):

This is what shared tenancy gets you, unpredictable results.

What is the size of the data set the queries run on? Although Craig says it sounds like busrty checkpoint activity, that doesn't make sense because this is RDS. It sounds more like cache fallout, e.g; your relations are falling out of cache.

You say you are running piops but m3.medium is not an EBS optimized instance.

You need at least:

1. High instance level. Make sure your memory is more than the active data set.
2. EBS optimized instances, see here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EBSOptimized.html
3. Lots of memory.
4. PIOPS

By the time you have all of that you will realize you will save a ton of money pushing PostgreSQL (or any database) to bare metal and leaving AWS to what it is good at, Memory and CPU (not IO).

Comment: The full data set is currently around 65GB, however the data is partitioned into tables, so there's a much smaller functional data set (only one set of tables is queried at a time).  That said, some of the tables are in the several million row range.

I don't think we're going to be able to have memory higher than the size of the data set and not bankrupt us.

Comment: Possibly also a dedicated instance, e.g. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/dedicated-instance.html . Frankly, I find that it's much more practical to use real hardware or a VPS with real local dedicated storage.

Comment: @MatthewFitzGerald-Chamberlain Given that, this sounds like a pretty typical cached vs uncached lookup cost issue. Occasional slow queries when you're fetching cold data. It's hard to say for sure without details, preferably `explain (buffers, analyze)` from both slow and fast cases. Look into the `auto_explain` module.

Comment: Is this really that unusual of a workload for RDS? I can understand that cached data is going to result in a faster query, but that a non-fully-primed cache resulting in a 10s query? Really?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this from within psql to get more details on query timing
EXPLAIN sql_statement
Also turn on more database logging. mysql has slow query analysis, maybe PostgreSQL has an equivalent.

Comment: `auto_explain` in particular, yes, and `pg_stat_statements`.